# Максимальное и минимальное значение в массиве

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти максимальное и минимальное значение в массиве. Наваял такой "быдлокод" =)

```
{
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
    if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1]) max = myArray[i];
    else min = myArray[i];
}
document.write(max);
document.write('</br>');
document.write(min);
```

Неверно работает. Подскажите почему. Не судить строго, я новичок в JS.

Comment: потому что Вы сравниваете два соседних элемента, а значит в `min` и `max` получите два последних элемента массива. чтобы заставить этот код работать как надо, сравнивайте каждый элемент с `min` и с `max`

но, мнится мне, существует более элегантное решение.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для поиска минимума вы должны делать отдельную проверку, сравнивая текущее myArray[i] с min, и если меньше -- менять min. Да и вообще, сравнивать надо не соседние значения, а текущие min и max с исследуемым myArray[i]

```
  min = myArray[0];
  max = min;
  for (i = 1; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
      if (myArray[i] > max) max = myArray[i];
      if (myArray[i] < min) min = myArray[i];
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает,вот только когда в массиве появляется 3х значное число,то оно почему-то не считается большим за 2х значное((

Comment: Это как? Массив для проверки можно увидеть?

Comment: как в коммент скрин сбросить? =))

Comment: Bведенo 5 числa
23
234
4
1
78
MAX 78 № 5
MIN 1 № 4

Різниця 77

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего комментатора. Решение ошибочно.

Answer (score 44):

Во имя Джавахарлала Неру, зачем такие сложности?!

```
>>> Math.min.apply(null, [1,3,5,-1,8,0])
-1
>>> Math.max.apply(null, [1,3,5,-1,8,0])
8
```

[Справочник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: ахаха, дико плюсую! недавно занялся js, про прототипы знаю, а про такие банальности нет!

Comment: а подкинете ссылку? чтоб я разобрался в этих строках и возможно тоже посмеялся ;)

или хоть скажите что почитать)

Comment: @Zein, "строки" это консоль Firebug, остальное здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Функция typeof(параметр) даст результат 'string' для строки и 'number' для числа. Вот два истинных выражения `typeof('1') == 'string'` и `typeof(1) == 'number'`.

Comment: @alexlz, не путайте человека, `typeof` не функция, а оператор. И к чему всё это?

Comment: Виноват, исправлюсь. А зачем -- чтобы проверить легче было, с чем работа идёт.

Comment: @alexlz, методы `Math` работают с `Number`, если же ОП тайно хочет лексикографическое сравнение, то решение будет кардинально иное.

Comment: @karmadro4 попытайтесь перечитать комментарии насчёт неправильных результатов (2х- и 3х-значные числа) и ввод с помощью prompt. Просто выясняли проблему.

Comment: @alexlz, это не результаты неправильные, а исходные данные :-P `Number(prompt())`

Comment: Ну я советовал, правда, parseInt, а не Number.

Comment: более короткий в ES2015: Math.max(...arr)

Comment: Да, но только есть один очень интересный нюансик. Всё бы хорошо, когда массив небольшой, но как только массив огромен, например о миллионе элементов, тогда Chrome, например, Вам гневно скажет, что Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded! Потому что apply создаёт стэк непомерных размеров. И тогда в этом случае используем стандартные средства))

Comment: Лучший ответ)))

Answer (score 6):

```
let arr = [22,4,7];
Math.min(...arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.prototype.min = function(){
    var min = parseInt(this[this.length-1]), el;
    for(var i=this.length-2; i>=0; i--){
        el = parseInt(this[i]);
        if(el<min){
            min = el;
        }
    }
    return min;
};

Array.prototype.max = function(){
    var max = parseInt(this[this.length-1]), el;
    for(var i=this.length-2; i>=0; i--){
        el = parseInt(this[i]);
        if(el>max){
            max = el;
        }
    }
    return max;
};

// использование:
var array = [1,3,5,-1,8,0];
document.write(array.min());// -1
document.write('</br>');
document.write(array.max());// 8
```

> Если в myArray не числа, а строки с цифрами.

**UPD:** добавил `parseInt`

Comment: тут та же проблема, с трехзначными числами..

Comment: не может такого быть: [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/LebNa/)

Comment: Может, может. Если в myArray не числа, а строки с цифрами.

Comment: я реализую в Dreamweaver,причина может быть в
next =  prompt( "Введите число массива : ");
хотя я не мудрец в яваскриптинге,если интересно могу выложить полностью код..

Comment: нет,там именно цифры)

Comment: По prompt вы получаете строку, пусть и содержащую цифры. если сравнивать "13" и "124", то "124" будет меньше. Лексически, по порядку символов. Сравнивается слева направо. Если же их преобразовать к целым (parseInt), то результат сравнения 13 и 124 будет ожидаемым. 13 будет меньше.

Answer (score 1):

//несколько строк кода и максимальное число известно
надо минимальное в if поменяйте > на <

```
var maxNum = [5, -1, 40, 355, 17, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < maxNum.length; i++) {
    if(maxNum[i] > maxNum[0]){
        maxNum[0] = maxNum[i];
    }

}
alert(maxNum[0]);
```

P.S.: И даже если в трехзначном числе будет первая цифра < первой цифры двухзначного все равно выведет трехзначное число

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [20, 3, 4, 5, -50, 100, 19, 200, 5000, 599];
let max = arr[0];

arr.forEach(function (elem, index) {

    if(index > 0 ){
        if(max < elem){
            max = elem;
        }

    }
});

console.log(max);
```

И Дело в шляпе, максимальное значение найдено!

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю через reduce:

```
let arrOfNumbers = [
    1, -4653, -3, 4, 5, 54, 684, 7, 8, 9, 10,
];


let maxNumber = (a, b) => {
    return a > b ? a : b;
},
    minNumber = (a, b) => {
        return a < b ? a : b
    };

console.log(arrOfNumbers.reduce(maxNumber))
console.log(arrOfNumbers.reduce(minNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Например для того, чтобы найти минимальное и максимальное значение в массиве. В функции используем метод sort():

```
`var min = function(list){
    list.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return list[0];
 }

console.log('min', min([-52, 56, 30, 29, -54, 0, -110]))`
```

Вернёт // -110

```
`var min = function(list){
    list.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    return list[0];
 }

console.log('min', min([-52, 56, 30, 29, -54, 0, -110]))`
```

Вернёт // 56

Ещё один пример сортировки массива c помощью методов Math.min и Math.max:

```
const min = (list) => Math.min(...list);
const max = (list) => Math.max(...list);
```