# Максимальное и минимальное значение в массиве на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Начало стандартное: я новичок в JavaScript.
Прежде чем задать вопрос, почитал тут:
[Максимальное и минимальное значение в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97055/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Задача: на вход функции подается строка с числами, разделенными пробелом. Нужно вернуть строку с максимальным и минимальным числом.

Примеры строк:
"4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
"10 2 -2 -10"
"1 -1"
"42"

Пример использования:
str = "10 2 -2 -10";
result = function(str);
Переменная result содержит 10 -10.

```
function fifth(str) {
    alert('Рассматриваем массив: ' + str);
    var arr = []
    var max = str[0];
    var min = str[0];
    arr = str.split(' ');
    alert('Количество элементов в массиве: ' + arr.length );
    alert('Массив: ' + arr);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // переберем весь массив
    // если элемент больше, чем в переменной, то присваиваем его значение переменной
    //alert('Значение arr[i]: '+ arr[i]);
        if (parseInt(max,10) < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i]; 
        } else if (parseInt(max,10) == arr[i]) {
            alert('Максимальное значение arr[i]: '+ arr[i] + ' равно ' + arr[i]);
            max = arr[i]; 
        }
        //alert('Проверяем на максимальное значение arr[i]: ' + arr[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        alert('Сравнимаем min ' + min + ' и ' + arr[i]);
        if (parseInt(min,10) > arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
        } else if (parseInt(min,10) == arr[i]) {
            alert('Минимальное значение arr[i]: '+ arr[i] + ' равно ' + arr[i]);
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    alert('Минимальное значение в массиве: ' + min + '\nМаксимальное значение в массиве: ' + max);
    result = max + ' ' + min;
    return result;
}
//str = "3 -6";
//str = '4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6';
//str = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6";
str = "42";
//var result = fifth("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
var result = fifth(str);

alert('Результат: ' + result);
```

Первая проблема, с которой столкнулся - если число из трёх цифр, то тоно не участвует в сравнении. Решил это используя parseInt(max,10).

Вторая проблема: если в функцию передать одно строку, состоящую из одного числа, например, 42, то результат не тот, который ожидается.

С Math.min экспериментировал:

```
function fifth(str) {


    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var result = 0;
    var arr = []
    arr = str.split('');

    var re = / /gi;
    var newstr = str.replace(re, ', ');
    alert('Рассматриваем массив: ' + str);
    alert('Рассматриваем массив: ' + newstr);
    min = Math.min.apply(Math, [arr]);
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, [arr]);
    alert('Минимальное значение в массиве: ' + min + '\nМаксимальное значение в массиве: ' + max);
    result = min + ' ' + max;

    return result;
}
str = "42";
//str = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6";
//var result = fifth("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
var result = fifth(str);

alert('Результат: ' + result);
```

В итоге получаю:

Минимальное значение в массиве: NaN 
Максимальное значение в массиве: NaN

Научите как правильно решить данную задачу.

Comment: Какой результат ожидается когда передается одно число? [42, 42]?

Comment: Ожидаю такой результат: "42 42", так как 42 является и минимальным и максимальным числом в переданной строке.

Answer (score 3):

[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

[`Spread Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const arrStr = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
console.log(getMiAnMax(arrStr))

function getMiAnMax(str) {
  const numbers = str.split(' ')
  return {
    min: Math.min(...numbers),
    max: Math.max(...numbers)
  }
}
```

[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arrStr = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
console.log(getMiAnMax(arrStr))

function getMiAnMax(str) {
  const numbers = str.split(' ').map(e => +e)
  return {
    min: numbers.reduce((a, v) => (v < a ? a = v : {}, a)),
    max: numbers.reduce((a, v) => (v > a ? a = v : {}, a))
  }
}
```

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const arrStr = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
console.log(getMiAnMax(arrStr))

function getMiAnMax(str) {
  const numbers = str.split(' ').map(e => +e)
  return {
    min: getMin(numbers),
    max: getMax(numbers)
  }
}

function getMin(arr) {
  let min = arr[0]
  arr.forEach(e => e < min ? min = e : {})

  return min
}

function getMax(arr) {
  let max = arr[0]
  arr.forEach(e => e > max ? max = e : {})

  return max
}
```

Answer (score 3):

• `var arr = []; arr = str.split(' ');`

Создаете ненужный массив `[]`, а можно на ходу сразу сделать `var arr = str.split(" ");`

• `var max = str[0]; var min = str[0];` — у вас в этом месте строка еще не превращена в массив, поэтому в переменные попадает первый **символ** строки `str`, `"42"[0] → "4"`

• Сравнение у вас работало неправильно, потому что разбивая строки через split, на выходе получаете массив из строк. А строки в JS сравниваются посимвольно:

```js
var a = "1111";
var b = "19";

console.log( a < b ) // true
// Сперва сравниваются `a[0]` и `b[0]` → равны, потом `a[1]` и `b[1]` → второй больше.
```

Чтобы такого не происходило, надо во время сравнения их привести к числовому типу, что и происходило у вас из-за `parseInt`. Можно эту же функцию использовать сразу во время создания массива и все строки превратить в числа:

`var arr = str.split(' ').map(parseInt);`

• Два цикла не обязательно: Можно сразу одним циклом проверить и min, и max:

```js
console.log( fifth("42") );
console.log( fifth("4 5 29 54 4 0 -64 1") );

function fifth(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ').map(Number);
  let min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if( arr[i] < min ) min = arr[i]; 
    if( arr[i] > max ) max = arr[i]; 
  }
  
  return min + " " + max;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за пояснения.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев Кстати, Math.min / max дают NaN, потому что ожидают список аргументов в виде `Math.min(1, 2, 3, 4)` а apply как раз берет полученный массив и превращает его в список аргументов для вызываемой функции... но у вас и так `arr` - массив, а вы заворачивали массив в еще один массив) `Math.min.apply(Math, arr);` — так, а не `[arr]`

Answer (score 1):

По второй проблеме ишите здесь ответ

```
var max = str[0];
var min = str[0];
arr = str.split(' ');
```

Попробуйте вместо этого:

```
arr = str.split(' ');
var max = arr[0];
var min = arr[0];
```

Comment: Благодарю. Помогло.
Расскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делал?
Хочется понять свою ошибку, чтобы её не повторять, а не просто скопировать код.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев вроде уже пояснили :-) Вы просто брали первый символ из строки, т.е. если число состоянло из 2 и более символов, у Вас иници ализировались переменные не корректно, т.к. нужно было уже из массива, в котором строка разбита